# retrieve id and data and then build dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following data I'm receiving from the service. The following console logs prints the following in browser:

```
console.log("Inside data");
console.log(data);

Inside data 
[[id=1, name=BOTTLE-1], [id=2, name=BOTTLE-2], [id=4, name=BOTTLE-3]]
```

If I want to build a options tag using jQuery, is it easy to extract the `id` as `1,3 and 4` and `name` for the value parameter of options tag and build a select dropdown?

For example, if I've the following code and if I want to work it like it is showing now.

```js
var data = "[[id=1, name=BOTTLE-1], [id=2, name=BOTTLE-2], [id=4, name=BOTTLE-3]]";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
<option  value="-">"Please Select"</option>
<option id = "1" value="BOTTLE-1">BOTTLE-1</option>
  <option id = "3" value="BOTTLE-2">BOTTLE-2</option>
  <option id="4" value="BOTTLE-3">BOTTLE-3</option>
</select>
```

Building part using append method should be easy but I am wondering if it's easy to extract the required values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```js
let data = "[[id=1, name=BOTTLE-1], [id=2, name=BOTTLE-2], [id=4, name=BOTTLE-3]]";

let codingRegex = /id=\d+, name=BOTTLE-\d+/g;
let matches = data.match(codingRegex);
let cars = $("#cars");
matches.forEach(match => {
  let temp = match.split(", ");
  let id = temp[0].replace("id=", ""),
    name = temp[1].replace("name=", "");
  let option = new Option();
  option.text = name;
  option.value = id;
  cars.append(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="-">"Please Select"</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks so I could probably use the `id` and `name` in your console log to generate option tags to generate the list using jQuery?

Comment: The solution is updated.

Comment: Do you think we can avoid `BOTTLE` from the line `let codingRegex = /id=\d+, name=BOTTLE-\d+/g;` ? That name can be different like `CAN-1` or something else and hence I'm wondering if we could remove hardcoding it?

Comment: Or if I can include a variable name in place of `BOTTLE`. Let's say if we have `let bName = "BOTTLE"`, then is it possible to do something like `let codingRegex = /id=\d+, name=bName-\d+/g;` ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = "[[id=1, name=BOTTLE-1], [id=2, name=BOTTLE-2], [id=4, name=BOTTLE-3]]";
let label = "BOTTLE";
let regExString="id=\\d+, name="+label+"-\\d+";
let regExp=new RegExp(regExString,"ig");
let matches = data.match(regExp);
let cars = $("#cars");
matches.forEach(match => {
  let temp = match.split(", ");
  let id = temp[0].replace("id=", ""),
    name = temp[1].replace("name=", "");
  let option = new Option();
  option.text = name;
  option.value = id;
  cars.append(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="-">"Please Select"</option>
</select>
```